# How to access variables from loaded DLL in python?

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, dll, ctypes

I have created a DLL (of the LZMA C SDK) to be used in my python code. I have used ctypes to access functions and specify parameters but i'm looking for a way to access variables (or what type of variables can be accessed !).

I'm new at ctypes and i don't know if it will be possible or not.

**update**
I have tried this (with different paths) but i get an error

```
 p1='E:\lzma\C\Util\LzmaLib\Debug\LzmaLib.dll'
 p2= 'E:/lzma/C/Util/LzmaLib/Debug/LzmaLib.dll'
 p3= 'E://lzma//C//Util//LzmaLib//Debug//LzmaLib.dll'

 lzma = ctypes.CDLL('E:/lzma/C/Util/LzmaLib/Debug/LzmaLib.dll');
 myGlobal = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lzma,'testVar')
 print "myGlobal "+ str(myGlobal)
```

i get

```
ValueError: symbol 'globVar' not found
```

I'm looking at SO since i didn't found usefull answers on google , thanks

Comment: You can access the library's exported data using the [`in_dll` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.in_dll), e.g. `c_int.in_dll(mylib, 'global_variable')`.

Comment: thanks please take a look at the update , i have recently began using python and  i don't know if this error is related to the DLL or to python !

Comment: The docs tell you that "library is the loaded shared library", not the path to the library, e.g. `lzma = ctypes.CDLL('E:/lzma/C/Util/LzmaLib/Debug/LzmaLib.dll');` `myGlobal = ctypes.c_int.in_dll(lzma, 'testVar')`. But expect the last part to fail if you haven't actually exported `testVar` when linking the DLL.

Comment: @eryksun that's  resolve the first issue you're right but now i get ValueError: symbol 'globVar' not found ... i have build the source file using VS and regenerate the DLL file but it seems that it's not found

Comment: VC++ exports symbols using [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) and [.def files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx).

Comment: thanks it worked using the link provided using #define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) and DllExport int testVar = 10; ... you can put your comment as answer to accept it